# 'accept' and 'deny' buttons are greyed out when receiving appointment request in Evolution

Tags: 11.04, evolution, email

On Ubuntu Natty I've got a weird problem using evolution. A coworker (using Outlook) sends me an appointment request. The mail is received in Evolution but the 'Accept' and 'Deny' buttons are greyed out and not clickable. Instead there is a message "searching for an existing version of this appointment" permanently visible.
I have no way of either accept or refuse the appointment.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem using evolution 2.32.2: I couldn't respond to Outlook invitations because the program waited forever with the message "searching for an existing version of this appointment".

I use a google calendar account as my default calendar, so the solution I found was to delete that calendar, and then add it again (not nice, but the best I could think of).

If you're not able to delete the calendar by right clicking on it (what seems to be another problem with evolution), then you have to open the gconf-editor, go to /apps/evolution/calendar/sources and delete the entries corresponding to the google calendar.

HTH,
Damian.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too.

I have a google calendar and an outlook calendar. I had to remove both, and re-set each up again, but this fixed the disabled buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I got this using exchange.  I just went to perms of Calendar and added my account from the GAL and set role to owner.
Hope this helps someone.